# Virtual Assistant Template Currently Uses TelemetryClient But Is Deprecated

Tags: c#, asp.net, botframework

In the Virtual Assistant template (https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/tree/master/templates/Virtual-Assistant-Template/csharp/Template/VA) the current `Startup.cs` file is using `TelemetryClient` on line 72. However, according to this github issue (https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1152), it is being deprecated.

What is the suggested change that I should make in my code in order to fix this going forward? Will the template be updated to reflect this?

Answer (score 1):

TelemetryClient is NOT being deprecated. Per the issue that you linked, `TelemetryConfiguration.Active` is being deprecated. A quick search of the VA bot github repo show that `TelemetryConfiguration.Active` is not used anywhere in the bot:

[image: github repo showing no results from searching for telemetryconfiguration.active]

Comment: Alright. So just to confirm, I should not be changing anything in my `Startup.cs` file despite this warning message? (https://imgur.com/makFzop)